# How to calculate the position of a character by parabola (using accelerometer)

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, surfaceview

I'm trying to recreate the bonus stage from Sonic the Hedgehog 2, in which he is traveling through a half-pipe collecting rings, on Android Studio. Right now I want to use the character's movement to be determined by the phone's accelerometer (Z-rotation) according to a parabola; the character's position must NOT exceed the edges of the pipe. The trouble is that no matter what I do with the x and y coordinates, the change in position is minimal. I'm using an emulator of a 1080 x 1920 Nexus 5. Any additional suggestions related to rotating or animating the character would also be appreciated.

Here's a video for reference: https://youtu.be/JgbFHHHE4Vk

And my onSensorChanged() method (x being the "left" value for the Bitmap, y being the "top", and z being the z-rotation value:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //tilt phone and change position
        float[] values = event.values;
        float z = values[0];
        x = (1080/360) * (z + 180);
        y = (-109 / 21609) * (x - 442) * (x - 442) + 975;
        Log.d("TAGz", "(" + x + ", " + y + ")");

    }
```

EDIT:

I checked the x and y coordinates through Logcat, and it seems that x, for a reason I cannot detect, is 540 when z is 180 degrees and is 540 when z is -180 degrees

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `(-109 / 21609)` because that's integer division. Try `(-109 / 21609.0)` instead. What are these magic numbers anyway?

Comment: Which ones? If it's the h and k values (442 and 975), those would be the coordinates of where my bitmap is initially placed (or at least should be). I also tried what you suggested, but Android Studio gave me syntax error, saying that 21609.0 is a double when it's asking for a float.

Comment: Well, that seems to be very device-specific code. Is that what you intended? Anyway, did changing to `(-109 / 21609.0)` work?

Comment: I did, but it gave me an incompatible types error because I'm using floats. As for the code being device-specific, I'm coding it specifically for the device I'm personally using.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a problem with it being integer division, because it does change when I'm rotating it, but only barely.

Comment: Make it a float: `(-109 / 21609f)`. Your y will always be 975 otherwise

Comment: I did as you said, but, although it moves a bit more now, it is still confined to the same space.